# Anima2D crashes in Unity3D 2019.2.0f

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Anima2D 1.1.8** can't get `CreateDefaultCurves` method in **Unity3D 2019.2.0f**:

```
AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found.
System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImpl (System.String name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Reflection.CallingConventions callConv, System.Type[] types, System.Reflection.ParameterModifier[] modifiers) (at <a8ed250850854b439cedc18931a314fe>:0)
System.Type.GetMethod (System.String name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr) (at <a8ed250850854b439cedc18931a314fe>:0)
Anima2D.AnimationWindowImpl_51_52_53.InitializeReflection () (at Assets/Anima2D/Scripts/Editor/AnimationWindowExtra/AnimationWindowImpl_51_52_53.cs:60)
Anima2D.AnimationWindowImpl_54.InitializeReflection () (at Assets/Anima2D/Scripts/Editor/AnimationWindowExtra/AnimationWindowImpl_54.cs:15)
Anima2D.AnimationWindowImpl_55.InitializeReflection () (at Assets/Anima2D/Scripts/Editor/AnimationWindowExtra/AnimationWindowImpl_55.cs:18)
Anima2D.AnimationWindowImpl_56.InitializeReflection () (at Assets/Anima2D/Scripts/Editor/AnimationWindowExtra/AnimationWindowImpl_56.cs:18)
Anima2D.AnimationWindowImpl_2017_1.InitializeReflection () (at Assets/Anima2D/Scripts/Editor/AnimationWindowExtra/AnimationWindowImpl_2017_1.cs:17)
Anima2D.AnimationWindowExtra..cctor () (at Assets/Anima2D/Scripts/Editor/AnimationWindowExtra/AnimationWindowExtra.cs:29)
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Anima2D.AnimationWindowExtra' threw an exception.
Anima2D.EditorUpdater.AnimationWindowTimeCheck () (at Assets/Anima2D/Scripts/Editor/EditorUpdater.cs:134)
Anima2D.EditorUpdater.Update () (at Assets/Anima2D/Scripts/Editor/EditorUpdater.cs:211)
Anima2D.EditorCallbacks+<>c.<.cctor>b__8_0 () (at Assets/Anima2D/Scripts/Editor/EditorUpdater.cs:25)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication.Internal_CallUpdateFunctions () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorApplication.cs:303)
```

I have checked in VS debagger and seems the instance has `CreateDefaultCurves`, so I can't get what's wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although in the forums it is said the latest version should fix the issue, I had to do my own fix. Try to substitute the problematic line with:

```
m_CreateDefaultCurvesMethod = m_AnimationWindowUtilityType.GetMethod("CreateDefaultCurves", new[] { m_AnimationWindowStateType });
```

This worked for me so far. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I will try it when I will have access to my laptop.

Comment: Fortunately, they fixed it in new version

Answer (score -1):

Thank you @eduilero You Save my day <3

=> Goto => Anima2d => Scripts => Editor => Find -> AnimationWindowImpl_51_52_53.cs
Search in class "m_CreateDefaultCurvesMethod" and Replace with this line
"m_CreateDefaultCurvesMethod = m_AnimationWindowUtilityType.GetMethod("CreateDefaultCurves", new[] { m_AnimationWindowStateType });"

and Boom.....

Comment: Each answer should be standalone, not reference other answers and be complete. It should also be containing english sentences or code and not arrows.